# How to solve '' aregImpute error : 'column_name' is constant ''

Tags: r, imputation, hmisc

I would like to delete some of the entries in my dataframe and impute them by using the remaining information by means of aregImpute function. However, when I randomly delete 25% of the data in some of the columns, some columns are left with only one single value (i.e. they are each equal to a constant number n). Then I get the following error:

```
Error in aregImpute(fmla, data = df_pmm_imp, n.impute = 5, nk = 0) : 
  X01154H.exp is constant
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
df = data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:100,1000,rep=TRUE)))
df[,10]= 0
smp_size = floor(0.25 * nrow(df))    
set.seed(123)
missing_ind = sample(seq_len(nrow(df)), size = smp_size)
df_pmm_imp[missing_ind,c(6:10)] = NA
fmla = as.formula(paste(" ~ ", paste(names(df), collapse=" +")))
impute_arg = aregImpute(fmla , data = df, n.impute=5, nk=0)

# Error in aregImpute(fmla, data = df, n.impute = 5, nk = 0) : 
          X10 is constant
```

Is there a way to fix this problem? I understand that a constant column does not provide much information, so it might be leading to problems. However, i don't think it should prevent the whole imputation. For instance, a better practice that comes to my mind would be to assign that constant value to all of the missing variables in the column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can delete the variable and then perform the imputation. It will work then ;) You can add it back to the data.frame in the end if you want. But what would you want with a constant variable anyway...?

Comment: Among the many columns with missing values that I want to impute, some have only constant non-missing values. The most straightforward approach is to impute these columns with their unique observed value and proceed with this data for the rest of the imputation. However, I was hoping to find a way to do this within the function, without me having the determine those columns and fill them before feeding the data to aregImpute().

Comment: This is what I am trying to do now but i keep getting errors. I tried these codes:      
`df = df %>%
       map_if(is_unique(.), ~ rep(unique(na.omit(.)), length(.)))                           df = df %>%
                 map_if(is_unique(.), ~ unique(na.omit(.)))                                        df = df %>%
                 mutate_if(is_unique(.), ~ unique(na.omit(.))) `                                     
I keep getting this error:                                                                                
`Error in probe(.x, .p) : length(.p) == length(.x) is not TRUE`